# Pocketsphinx, Python дает ошибку ValueError: signal only works in main thread

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, python-3.6, pocketsphinx

Есть проект на Flask. Python-скрипт содержит `pocketsphinx AudioFile`.

Код

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, json, request, jsonify, redirect
app = Flask(__name__)
import os
from pocketsphinx import AudioFile, get_model_path, get_data_path
from werkzeug.utils import secure_filename

model_path = get_model_path()
data_path = get_data_path()

@app.route("/")
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')
@app.route("/", methods=['POST'])
def speech2text():
    _file = request.form['file']
    if _file:
        _file_name = _file.split('/')[-1]
        p = os.popen("sox static/load_files/audio/" + _file_name + " -r 16000 -c 1 static/load_files/audio/16khz_" +_file_name)
        config = {
            'verbose': True,
            'audio_file': os.path.join(data_path, "static/load_files/audio/16khz_"+ _file_name),
            'buffer_size': 2048,
            'no_search': False,
            'full_utt': False,
            'hmm': os.path.join(model_path, 'cmusphinx-ru-5.2'),
            'lm':   False,
            'jsgf': os.path.join(model_path, 'grammar.jsgf'),
            'dict': os.path.join(model_path, 'dictionary.dic'),
        }
        audio = AudioFile(**config)
        for phrase in audio:
            result_text = phrase
        return result_text
    else:
        return 'Увы, распознавание текста не удалось :('

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=8080, ssl_context='adhoc')
```

При попытке обработать поступающий файл вылетает ошибка

```
[2019-02-21 12:20:00,148] ERROR in app: Exception on / [POST]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/mmamonova/speach2text-commands-sphinx/env/lib/python3.6/site-packa                       ges/flask/app.py", line 2292, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/home/mmamonova/speach2text-commands-sphinx/env/lib/python3.6/site-packa                       ges/flask/app.py", line 1815, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/home/mmamonova/speach2text-commands-sphinx/env/lib/python3.6/site-packa                       ges/flask/app.py", line 1718, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/home/mmamonova/speach2text-commands-sphinx/env/lib/python3.6/site-packa                       ges/flask/_compat.py", line 35, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/home/mmamonova/speach2text-commands-sphinx/env/lib/python3.6/site-packa                       ges/flask/app.py", line 1813, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/home/mmamonova/speach2text-commands-sphinx/env/lib/python3.6/site-packa                       ges/flask/app.py", line 1799, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "app.py", line 32, in speech2text
    audio = AudioFile(**config)
  File "/home/mmamonova/speach2text-commands-sphinx/env/lib/python3.6/site-packa                       ges/pocketsphinx/__init__.py", line 157, in __init__
    signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, self.stop)
  File "/home/enosikova/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/signal.py", line 47, in signal
    handler = _signal.signal(_enum_to_int(signalnum), _enum_to_int(handler))
ValueError: signal only works in main thread
172.31.32.146 - - [21/Feb/2019 12:20:00] "POST / HTTP/1.1" 500 -
```

Путем проверок выяснила, что ошибка возникает из-за строчки

```
audio = AudioFile(**conf)
```

Подскажите, как можно решить эту проблему?
Спасибо

Comment: Интересно... а если так `app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=8080, ssl_context='adhoc', processes=True)`?

Comment: @gil9red, тот же результат

Answer (score 0):

Данная ошибка возникает из-за того, что `Flask` использует несколько потоков, а `pocketsphinx` требует, чтобы `signal` обрабатывался только в главном потоке. Один из возможных способов решения - установить `threaded=False` в вызове `app.run()`.

Пример:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=8080, ssl_context='adhoc', threaded=False)
```